# How to redirect "/" to "/home.html" only if the file "/index.html" does not physically exists?

Tags: apache, file, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found a way to redirect (not load, but change the URL) "`/`" to "`/home.html`". And now I want to add a `RewriteCond` to avoid the redirection if the file "`/index.html`" exists.

I tried (without the comments), but it didn't worked :

```
# We check that we comes from "domain.tld/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/

# We check that there is no index.html file at the site's root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}index\.html !-f

# We redirect to home.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}home\.html [R=301,L]
```

Help me Obi-wan Kenobi... You're my only hope!

---

**@Gumbo**

It's a little bit more complicated than the above example. In fact, I manage both localhost and production development with the same .htaccess, so I tried something like this (following your answer) :

```
# Redirect domain.tld/ to domain.tld/home.html (only if domain.tld/index.html does not exists)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}index\.html !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}domain.tld/www/index\.html !-f
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}home\.html [R=301,L]
```

I looked at the path returned by "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}domain.tld/www/index.html" and it's exactly the path of my index.html file... nevertheless, it didn't worked too. :(

By the way, thanks for the "^$" astuce to avoid "%{REQUEST_URI} =/" ! \o/

Any idea why ?

Comment: Then what is the physical path of the directory this .htaccess file is located in?

Comment: In localhost: "/home/{user}/localhost/domain.tld/www/.htaccess", in production: "/home/vhosts/domain.tld/www/.htaccess". The index.html is in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

The file check `-f` requires a valid file system path. But `%{REQUEST_URI}index\.html` is not a file system path but a URI path. You can either use `-F` instead to check the existence via a subrequest. Or use *DOCUMENT_ROOT* to build a valid file system path:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html !-f
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}home.html [R=301,L]
```

Furthermore, the other condition can be accomplished with the pattern of `RewriteRule`. As you’re using mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file, the corresponding path prefix is stripped (in case of the document root directory: `/`) so that the remaining path is an empty string (matched by `^$`).

Comment: I answered you in my question post, @Gumbo section.

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to httpd.conf (apaches config file) you could set the default page in there.

Something like this:

```
<IfModule dir_module>  
    DirectoryIndex index.html home.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. I want the URL to be changed to "domain.tld/home.html", and not the server to load the home.html file (that doesn't exists, by the way ^^). There's RewriteRule after to manage the home.html => index.php?page=home...

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. You should update your question to include that part (unless i am just missing it).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the rule set that you posted in your update, you have a bit of a logical error going on. Right now, one of your `RewriteCond` conditions will always be true, since it seems likely that both index files will never exist in the same environment (one exists in development, the other in production). Since you've OR'ed them together, this means that your `RewriteRule` will never be ignored due to the condition block.

It's simple enough to fix (I've also added additional forward slashes, since `DOCUMENT_ROOT` typically [doesn't have a trailing slash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot)):

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domain.tld/www/index.html !-f
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}home.html [R=301,L]
```

Note too that you could setup a [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) with a local host name so that your development and production would be similar in terms of relative paths.